# Connecting to Google APIs using next-auth

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, next-auth

I am trying to connect to the Google's APIs using Next's OAuth 2.0 protocol. I am able to successfully log in to my web app using my google account, however retrieving the token scoped for access to the sheets API is where I'm having the most trouble. To be specific, even with my authOptions being set up, I cannot get the token to be passed to my API route appropriately. Any guidance or general direction would be appreciated.

`[...nextauth].js file`

```
export const authOptions = {
  theme: {
    colorScheme: 'light'
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ account, profile }) {
      if (account.provider === "google") {
        return profile.email_verified && profile.email.endsWith("@company.com")
      }
      return false
    },
  },
  jwt: async ({ token, user, account }) => {
    console.log('in jwt', {user, token, account})
    if (user) {
      token.user = user
      token.role = user.role
    }
    if (account) {
      token.accessToken = account.access_token
      token.refreshToken = account.refresh_token
    }
    return token
  },
  session: ({ session, token, user }) => {
    token.accessToken
    return {
      ...session,
      user: {
        ...session.user,
        role: token.role,
        accessToken: token.accessToken,
        refreshToken: token.refreshToken
      }
    }
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: GOOGLE_OAUTH_ID,
      clientSecret: GOOGLE_OAUTH_SECRET,
      checks: 'none',
      authorizationUrl: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?hd=company.com',
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
        },
      },
    })
  ],
}
```

`sheets.js`

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)
    const user = session?.user

    if (!session) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: 'No Session Active' })
    }

    const accessToken = user?.accessToken
    const refreshToken = user?.refreshToken

    if (!accessToken) {
      res.status(401).json({ error: 'No Access Token' })
    }

    if (!refreshToken) {
      res.status(401).json({ error: 'No Refresh Token' })
    }

    const { sheetId, sheetName, range } = req.query

    const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_SECRET,
      redirectUri: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL
    })

    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
      access_token: accessToken,
      refresh_token: refreshToken
    })

    if (oauth2Client.isTokenExpiring()) {
      const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.refreshAccessToken()
      const newAccessToken = tokens.access_token

      session.user.accessToken = newAccessToken
    }

    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: oauth2Client })
    const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: sheetId,
      range: `${sheetName}!${range}`
    })

    res.status(200).json(response)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred: ', error)
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Error' })
  }
}
```

This is also relevant, but my call to the API route in one of my compnenets:

```
const fetchSheetsDialogData = async() => {
    try{
      const sheetId = 'SHEET_ID'
      const sheetName = 'SHEET_NAME'
      const range = 'SHEET_RANGE'

      const sheet = await fetch(`/api/google/sheets?sheetId=${encodeURIComponent(sheetId)}&sheetName=${encodeURIComponent(sheetName)}&range=${encodeURIComponent(range)}`)
      
      if(sheet.ok){
        const data = await sheet.json()
        console.log(data)
      } else{
        console.error('Failed to fetch data from the spreadsheet')
      }

    } catch(error){
      console.error('Error retrieving sheets data: ', error)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `[...nextauth].js` file:
Was able to successfully figure it out. For the first file mentioned in my question, the async parameters `jwt` and `session` were not within the callback, so a syntax error there. I also overcomplicated the hell out of them, they don't need to be that complicated. You need to set the session strategy to `jwt`, which looks like this:

```
session: {
    strategy: 'jwt'
  },
```

Also need to specify the scopes `openid`, `profile`, and `email`.

Now the `sheets.js` file:
To get the token properly, you need the API handler function `getToken()`. This will return a token object with you access token inside, which you need to connect to the sheets API with. Because of how it is set up at my company, I did not need to specify the `clientSecret`, `clientId`, or `redirectUri`, so those can be removed. The `if(!refreshToken)` statement will always fail because Next.js does not return a refresh token, so be aware of that, as that was causing me issues.

That should summarize all the issues I had, so I will now post the complete corrected files:

`[...nextauth].js`

```
const authOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt'
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ account, profile }) {
      if (account.provider === "google") {
        return profile.email_verified && profile.email.endsWith("@company.com")
      }
      return false
    },
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token
        token.refreshToken = account.refresh_token
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken
      session.refreshToken = token.refreshToken
      return session
    }
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: GOOGLE_OAUTH_ID,
      clientSecret: GOOGLE_OAUTH_SECRET,
      checks: 'none',
      authorizationUrl: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?hd=company.com',
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: 'openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
        },
      },
    })
  ],
  theme: {
    colorScheme: 'light'
  },
}
```

`sheets.js`

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)
    const token = await getToken({ req })
    console.log(token)

    if (!session) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: 'No Session Active' })
    }

    const accessToken = token?.accessToken
    const refreshToken = token?.refreshToken

    if (!accessToken) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: 'No Access Token' })
    }

    const { sheetId, sheetName, range } = req.query

    const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2({})

    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
      access_token: accessToken,
      refresh_token: refreshToken
    })

    if (oauth2Client.isTokenExpiring()) {
      const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.refreshAccessToken()
      const newAccessToken = tokens.access_token

      session.user.accessToken = newAccessToken
    }

    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: oauth2Client })

    const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: sheetId,
      range: `${sheetName}!${range}`
    })

    return res.status(200).json(response.data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred: ', error)
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Error' })
  }
}
```

Also was not "returing" `res.status('INSERT STATUS CODE')`, so that was also causing errors. Just be aware of that as well.

NOTE: I have not tested if the `isTokenExpiring()` if statement works, so just be aware of that if you use this for your future programming.